# Generate a configuration file from a script using PERL

Tags: perl, config

I have a following hash:

```
my %hash = (
  'vars' => {
    'var10' => 'val10',
    'var20' => {
      'var30' => 'val30',
    },
  },
);
```

I want to generate a configuration file from this hash that looks like this:

```
vars
  var10 val10
  var20
    var30 val30
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could, of course, roll your own solution.

However, I'd recommend using [`YAML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/YAML/lib/YAML.pod)

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use YAML;

my %hash = (
    'vars' => {
        'var10' => 'val10',
        'var20' => { 'var30' => 'val30', },
    },
);

print Dump \%hash;
```

Outputs:

```
---
vars:
  var10: val10
  var20:
    var30: val30
```

Comment: Thank you, now I can work with this output without any difficulty! But please, say me what is means a solution rolling? I'm not saying about this, but if it is urgent, later I would add a new keys and a values dynamically. Ah, nothing, now I read about YAML. =)

Comment: "Rolling your own solution" is an English programming [idiom](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:English_idioms) for *creating* one's own solution.  The YAML framework will easily let you add keys and values later though.